# Distance x pixels from right CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm adding a custom CSS to my website (in order to translate) and my programmer gave me the following code:

```html
<div class="gtranslate_wrapper"></div>
<script>
  window.gtranslateSettings = {
    "default_language": "en",
    "detect_browser_language": true,
    "languages": ["en", "pt"],
    "wrapper_selector": ".gtranslate_wrapper",
    "flag_size": 16,
    "horizontal_position": "right",
    "vertical_position": "top",
    "alt_flags": {
      "en": "usa",
      "pt": "brazil"
    }
  }
</script>
<script src="https://cdn.gtranslate.net/widgets/latest/fc.js" defer></script>
```

However, I would like to distance something like 300px from right, instead of being in top right, so how can I do it?

Tried something like "horizontal_position":"right:300px" but it didn't work, throwing the flags and codes all the way left. Also tried to add a "border-right: 300px solid transparent" feature, leaving the same results.

Comment: By inspecting the code I found that `horizontal_position` is concatenated directly into an inline CSS string: `if(horizontal_position!='inline')
widget_code='<div class="gt_switcher_wrapper" style="position:fixed;'+vertical_position+':15px;'+horizontal_position+':15px;z-index:999999;">'+widget_code+'</div>';`. This means that you can use a small trick with a [CSS custom property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties): `horizontal_position: 'right:300px;--unused'`. *Disclaimer:* I don't know anything about GTranslate.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what kind of code is behind the script and the javascript file which is referenced.

So my guess is, that this is generating something which is put the  tag:

```
<div style="overflow: hidden">
    <div style="float: left">&nbsp;</div>
    <div style="float: right" class="gtranslate_wrapper"></div>
</div>​

<script>window.gtranslateSettings = {"default_language":"en","detect_browser_language":true,"languages":["en","pt"],"wrapper_selector":".gtranslate_wrapper","flag_size":16,"horizontal_position":"right","vertical_position":"top","alt_flags":{"en":"usa","pt":"brazil"}}</script>
<script src="https://cdn.gtranslate.net/widgets/latest/fc.js" defer></script>
```